# Extjs4 grid column accepting accented characters and tabpanel title including accented chars(special characters in spanish).

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

Extjs4 grid column accepting accented characters and tabpanel title including accented chars(special characters in spanish). Grid column should display it properly and title of tab should also display it properly, Right now its shown as question mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTF-8 everywhere, in you web page, javascript, json between client and server, in your server database, just everywhere.

Then you'll have **NO** problems with accented characters in any language, Spanish included.